# convert string to array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a string

`var str = '[SYSTEM, Test, check]'`

I want to convert this String into array in order to access these values separately., like..

```
var array = ['SYSTEM', 'Test', 'check'];
```

Comment: I assume that you mean `var str = '[SYSTEM, Test, check]'`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that by removing the beginning and end brackets and then splitting the string by ', '.

```
var array = str.replace(/\[|\]/g,'').split(', ');
```

This uses a regex to remove the brackets and than the split method to make the array

To elaborate a little more... I use /[|]/ to look for instances of [ and ]. I flag the regex as global (the g) in order to find all instances of it. Then I replace the instances with an empty string. Once all the instances have been removed, I split the string into an array based off of a comma and space seperator ', '

**UPDATE:**

As per the comments, you should check for the brackets at the beginning and end of the string, since we will assume you want brackets from any other values.

```
var array = str.replace(/(^\[|\]$)/g, '').split(', ');
```

Comment: This will remove `[` and `]` from array values as well... http://jsfiddle.net/T886K/

Comment: I would even use anchors to avoid replacing brackets inside strings: `/^\[|\]$/`

Comment: Nice, but that's better to check if brackets are the first and last characters : `str.replace(/^\[|\]$/g,'').split(', ')`. EDIT : I edited your answer (editception :) ).

Comment: Actually I don't know anything about Regular Exps or what else is this , so can you please explain a little or just give an external link to study about this..

Comment: @AnkitLamba https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions would be helpful to look at. I tried to explain some in the paragraph right about "UPDATE"

Answer (score 4):

```
var array = str.substring(1, str.length - 1).split(", ");
```